# Reading Insde of a Xdocument

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

Hi everyone i am Probably doing this wrong but im trying to get the inside elements in a xml document and every time i try the for loop it seems to return everything in one lump sum

sample xml

```
<RStream> 
  <CmdResponse>
  </CmdResponse> 
  <TranResponse>
    <ProductData> 
      <ProductCat1>02</ProductCat1> 
      <ProductSubCat1>000</ProductSubCat1>
      <ProductQty1>32.00</ProductQty1> 
      <ProductCat2>03</ProductCat2> 
      <ProductSubCat2>000</ProductSubCat2> 
      <ProductQty2>72.00</ProductQty2> 
    </ProductData>
  </TranResponse>
</RStream>

foreach (XElement element in doc.Descendants("ProductData"))
{
    MessageBox.Show(element.Name.ToString());
    MessageBox.Show(element.Value);
}
```

I get a response of ProductData
then a response of

[image]

Im Trying to get a response in the loop that will show me 
ProductCat1 then 02 
and so on there could be a unlimited number of responses in ProductData

Comment: Question unclear. What is the desired output for the given xml? Do you want to print all child elements of the `ProductData`?

Comment: @Gliad Green Sorry i was unclear im looking for the output ProductCat1 then 02 and on the next loop ProductSubCat1 and 000

Comment: What do you mean by output? For the given data what is the result you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use another `foreach` on sub children of `ProductData`:

Try this for example :

```
foreach (XElement element in doc.Descendants("ProductData"))
{
    foreach (XElement subElement in element.Elements())
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(subElement.Name.ToString());
        Debug.WriteLine(subElement.Value);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks this is perfect i did not realize i needed to do a second foreach loop

Answer (score 1):

You can easily solve this problem by using the Visual Studio debugger with a breakpoint. Doing so, you can inspect the value of the variable `element`, which is this

```
<ProductData>
  <ProductCat1>02</ProductCat1>
  <ProductSubCat1>000</ProductSubCat1>
  <ProductQty1>32.00</ProductQty1>
  <ProductCat2>03</ProductCat2>
  <ProductSubCat2>000</ProductSubCat2>
  <ProductQty2>72.00</ProductQty2>
</ProductData>
```

For getting what you want, you need this modified code:

```
foreach (XElement element in doc.Descendants("ProductData"))
{
    foreach (var xElement in element.Elements())
    {
        MessageBox.Show(xElement.Name.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show(xElement.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks to you as well as the answers are basically the same did not understand i needed an additional loop